# How to launch Dolphin file manager from command line or bash script (and give it a path)?

Tags: command-line, bash, dolphin

I want to open a Dolphin window from a bash script. It may not be relevant to the question, but I will be connecting to an SFTP location in Dolphin.

First I tried this command from my script:

```
dolphin sftp://MyHost:1234
```

This results in several warnings:

```
kdeinit4: Shutting down running client. klauncher: Exiting on signal
15 Connecting to deprecated signal
QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. KDE Daemon (kded) already
running. QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. kbuildsycoca4 running...
kbuildsycoca4(13252) KConfigGroup::readXdgListEntry: List entry
MimeType in "/usr/NX/share/applnk/x-nxclient/nxclient.desktop" is not
compliant with XDG standard (missing trailing semicolon). 
kbuildsycoca4(13252) parseLayoutNode: The menu spec file contains a
Layout or DefaultLayout tag without the mandatory Merge tag inside.
Please fix your file.  kbuildsycoca4(13252) parseLayoutNode: The menu
spec file contains a Layout or DefaultLayout tag without the mandatory
Merge tag inside. Please fix your file.  dolphin(13244)
KXMLGUI::ActionList::plug: Index  19  is not within range (0 -  11 
kio_trash(13254) TrashProtocol::createUDSEntry: couldn't stat 
"/home/user/.local/share/Trash/files/.DS_Store"
```

Next I tried this command from my script:

```
dbus-launch dolphin sftp://MyHost:1234
```

This results in even more warnings:

```
kdeinit4: Shutting down running client. Connecting to deprecated
signal
QDBusConnectionInterface::serviceOwnerChanged(QString,QString,QString)
QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. QDBusConnection: session
D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may
misbehave. kbuildsycoca4 running... QDBusObjectPath: invalid path ""
QObject::connect: Cannot connect (null)::deviceFound(Device*) to
BlueDevilDaemon::deviceFound(Device*) QObject::connect: Cannot connect
QTimer::timeout() to (null)::stopDiscovery() QDBusConnection: session
D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may
misbehave. QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. QDBusConnection: session
D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may
misbehave. QDBusConnection: session D-Bus connection created before
QCoreApplication. Application may misbehave. QDBusConnection: session
D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may
misbehave. No outputs have backlight property QDBusConnection: session
D-Bus connection created before QCoreApplication. Application may
misbehave. dolphin(13176) KXMLGUI::ActionList::plug: Index  19  is not
within range (0 -  11  QDBusConnection: name 'org.kde.kglobalaccel'
had owner '' but we thought it was ':1.5' Warning from helper: reading
brightness failed with error code  5 "No such file or directory" 
Warning from helper: reading brightness failed with error code  5 "No
such file or directory"  kded(13187)
PowerDevilUPowerBackend::brightness:
org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.brightness failed  Warning from
helper: writing brightness failed with error code  5 "No such file or
directory"  Warning from helper: writing brightness failed with error
code  5 "No such file or directory"  kded(13187)
PowerDevilUPowerBackend::setBrightness:
org.kde.powerdevil.backlighthelper.setbrightness failed 
kio_trash(13205) TrashProtocol::createUDSEntry: couldn't stat 
"/home/user/.local/share/Trash/files/.DS_Store"
```

How do I launch Dolphin file manager from a bash script and give it an (SFTP) path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help:

[Using ssh to browse remote file system in Dolphin & Konqueror on KDE](http://www.binarytides.com/ssh-dolphin-konqueror-kde/)

and then redirect the stderr to a file or /dev/null like so:

```
dolphin sftp://<usr@host>/ 2> /dev/null
```